# Changing animation lengths for individual animations

Tags: animation, unity

I have an animation clip that's 100 frames and another that is 120 frames, and I want to export the animation into unity later. I've set the frame range end in blender to 120 frames, that way the animation with 120 frames won't get cut off. However, I'm noticing when I play the 100 frame animation, the slider keeps going even after the end of the animation. THEN  it repeats the track when it gets to 120.
[image]

**Is there a way to set different max frame ranges for different animations?** Or will Unity automatically make the animation length the last keyframe in the anim when I export it? Thanks in advance!